# <NSStreamDelegate> not called in Swift project

Tags: objective-c, swift, sockets

I am working with Socket TCP in Swift and use Objective c file in Swift project ,after I call initNetworkCommunication() **stream is not open**

Anyone have any idea why??

**.h file:**

```
@interface SocketTCP : NSObject <NSStreamDelegate>
{
    NSInputStream *inputStream;
    NSOutputStream *outputStream;
    NSString* CmdType,*IpAddress;
}
```

**.m file:**

```
- (void) initNetworkCommunication:(NSString*) SERVER_IP :(int)SERVER_PORT {

    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)SERVER_IP, 5555, &readStream, &writeStream);

    inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
    NSLog(@"She be opened, sir!");

}


- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

    switch (streamEvent) {

        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
             NSLog(@"Stream opened");
        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
             NSLog(@"Stream has space available.");
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
             NSLog(@"Stream has byte available.");
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
             NSLog(@"Can not connect to the host!");
             break;
        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:

        default:
             NSLog(@"Unknown event");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know where you found that code but `- (void) initNetworkCommunication:(NSString*) SERVER_IP :(int)SERVER_PORT` is clearly not a recommended way to declare methods, it should be: `- (void) initNetworkCommunication:(NSString*)serverIP andPort:(int)serverPort`.

Comment: thanks for comment, but The point is - (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent  not called !!